# Using ACM style produces wrong page size

Tags: acm

I'm using the [ACM "Tighter Alternate style"](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates) to write a document. The submission instructions state that I have to create a PDF in US letter format but unfortunately, my PDF is A4. How can I change this to US letter?

I have tried the geometry package (`\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}`), but this produces 6 instead of 4 pages and I can read everywhere, that there are only slight differences between both sizes... Additionally, I looked into the config.ps as described [here](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sigfaq#a5), but proposed lines to change exist both in my config.ps.

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an officially (I asked ACM support) accepted way to do this

```
\pdfpagewidth=8.5in
\pdfpageheight=11in
```

Comment: Thank you very much! They should put this on the ACM site; it's missing this critical piece of information for TeX authors.